# Untyped strength bonus in Herolab

Tags: pathfinder-1e, hero-lab

I am trying to create an object in Herolab for pathfinder that grants an untyped strength bonus.  What I am starting from is

```
<thing id="ioHBSTR2" name="Hero Bonus, +2 STR" description="+2 Bonus to STR" compset="Wondrous">
 <usesource source="primetown"/>
 <tag group="Helper" tag="EquipMag"/>
 <tag group="Helper" tag="ShowSpec"/>
 <tag group="gType" tag="Wonder"/>
 <tag group="Helper" tag="EquipAvail"/>
 <eval phase="First">#enhancementbonus[hero.child[aSTR], 2]</eval>
 <!-- <eval phase="First">#bonus[hero.child[aSTR], 2]</eval> -->
</thing>
```

This gives an enhancement bonus.  The commented line is my attempt to convert it to an untyped bonus, which gives an error.

How do I convert this to an untyped bonus?

As a more general question, is there a document that says "these are the expressions that you can put into a script for hero lab?

Comment: [These tutorials may help.](http://forums.wolflair.com/showthread.php?t=21688) They don't indicate the # shortcut you can use, but there's a bit about writing it out the long way in the 201 tutorial.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what ability or effect grants an *untyped* bonus to Strength in Pathfinder?

Comment: I forget exactly what I was trying to do with it, but I think it was for a house rule.  So the general answer is "none".  Given I was trying to make it rather than just using a download, it was almost certainly a house rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

hero.child[[aSTR].field[Bonus].value = hero.child[[aSTR].field[Bonus].value + 2

I don´t have my herolab right here so I can´t test it right now.

http://tekkmage.com/content/joomla/path-list/9-pathfinder